# How should I mock Arrays.asList in Java Unit Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a Unit Test in a Java app and I get error while executing the following line:

`when(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains(countryCode)).thenReturn(true);`

The error message does not mention mocking, but I think the problem is related to not mocking
`Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()` part in the `when` method. So, how should I treat this line? Normally I mock services and repositoories, but ı am not sure if I should mock this part like `@Mock Locale locale;`. I tried it but not worked.

Here is the error message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
```

**Note:** I also tried `doReturn(true).when(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains(countryCode));` but not worked.

Comment: Why would `Locale.getISOCountries()` _not_ contain GB, given the method "Returns a list of all 2-letter country codes defined in ISO 3166"? What do you think you're setting up with the mock here?

Comment: Maybe if you include the stack trace of the failed test and the related code of such test instead of that setup line, you would obtain an useful answer.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks amigo, I added. Any help pls?

Comment: @Alex `Locale.getISOCountries()` will _always_ contain "GB" because that's a country code defined in ISO3166-2. Given that, you simply don't need to do _anything_ to ensure your test runs with that behavior. Remove the line. And drop the attitude, you're the one asking for the help here.

Comment: "and that is possible not to contain that value" `Locale.getISOCountries()` always returns the same list. It will not return an array containing arbitrary strings. You shouldn't try to make a test do things that can never actually occur in production code, because then you're testing the test, not the actual behavior.

Comment: I meant that: `when(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains("XYZ")).thenReturn(true);`

Comment: **@DOWNED_VOTERS** Why voted down downed users?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: don't try to mock this. For one thing, you can't; for another, you shouldn't.

It is best to use the default behavior. Remove the line where you attempt to configure this behavior with Mockito.

If you insist that you need to be able to use an arbitrary list of countries, see the section on "dependency injection" below, noting the caveat mentioned.

---

Attempting to mock the return value of `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains(countryCode)` would specifically mean that you are trying to alter the behavior of the `List<String>` returned by `Arrays.asList` when given a particular `String[]` as an argument.

You can't with Mockito, because it isn't magic: it doesn't allow replacement of behavior for arbitrary expressions.

The way something like `when(aMock.method(123)).thenReturn("hello")` works is that the mock object - `aMock` - records that `method` was invoked with an argument `123`. This information is pushed onto a stack, from which the `when` method is able to retrieve it and deal with it.

The pushing-onto-the-stack is only done if `aMock` is an object that Mockito has created: Mockito implements the methods of an interface/overrides the methods of a class to do this recording.

None of the objects involved in `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains("GB")` were created by Mockito. As such, none of these objects have methods which capture the invocation and push it onto the stack; Mockito basically can't see that anything is going on, so when the `when` call comes, it's just using whatever state is hanging around in Mockito. The error message shown:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
```

indicates that it thinks you are configuring the behavior of a `toString` method, nothing obviously to do with `Arrays.asList`, `Locale.getISOCountries()` or `List.contains`.

For the same reason, you can't mock the return value of `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())` or `Locale.getISOCountries()`: they're just not objects Mockito knows anything about.

So, that's why this mocking *doesn't* work. On to why you don't want to do it in the first place:

---

[`List.contains` has specific semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)), namely that it returns true if and only if the argument is in the list. There are implications of this, such as `aList.contains(o) == true` implying that a call to `aList.indexOf(o)` would have returned a non-negative value.

This means that the consequences of mocking `contains` would be either:

1. You have to also configure the mocking of other methods on the list such that the behavior of the list is consistent with that result of `List.contains` (so, `indexOf`, `subList`, `iterator` etc) - and, how the mock should behave if you were to set the element equal to `o` to something else (because `Arrays.asList` allows that);

   or
2. You don't configure the other mocking, and your `List` doesn't have behavior consistent with an actual `List`, which will have unpredictable effects on the behavior of your code.

But you don't actually have to worry about doing 1. (which is good, because it would be essentially impossible to do correctly, e.g. such that copies of the list have the same `contains` behavior) or 2. (which is good, because introducing the unpredictability of a broken `List` is simply a bad idea): `Arrays.asList` has a perfectly-working implementation of the `List` interface; all you need to make sure is that the argument you pass in (in this case `Locale.getISOCountries()`) contains the element that you want.

Mocking of the return value of `Arrays.asList(...).contains` is neither necessary nor desirable.

---

So, the problem now is shifted from one of ensuring that `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains(countryCode)` to one of ensuring that `Locale.getISOCountries()` has at least one element that is equal to `countryCode`.

As stated in [the Javadoc of `Locale.getISOCountries()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getISOCountries()):

> Returns a list of all 2-letter country codes defined in ISO 3166

Given that GB ([as was originally asked](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69390613/1)) is a 2-letter country code defined in ISO 3166, it will always (or, at least, until ISO3166 is changed) be an element of the array returned by `Locale.getISOCountries()`.

Hence, the array returned by `Locale.getISOCountries()` is going to contain `"GB"`, so `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains("GB")`, without actually doing anything.

---

But then there is the question of making `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains(countryCode)` true, for an arbitrary `countryCode`. By the argument above, you want to effect this only by ensuring that `Locale.getISOCountries()` has an element equal to `countryCode`.

If `countryCode` is another two-letter ISO-3166-2 country code, this already works, as in the GB case.

If `countryCode` is not an ISO country code, you absolutely should not want to make a method return it if that method is documented to return only ISO-3166-2 country codes, because this wouldn't happen in production code.

---

Mocking should not be used as a way to do arbitrary things in tests.

You only ever want a test to test things which can *actually* happen in production code. Ideally, you use "the real thing"; [test doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) (of which a mock is one type) come into play only if using "the real thing" is hard because the real thing is slow, expensive, difficult to reproduce (e.g. an error condition like a network error or full disk) etc. But, the testing double should only be doing things you'd see for real.

So, even if you could mock `Locale.getISOCountries()` to ensure that it returned an array containing a non-ISO-3166-2 `countryCode`, you *shouldn't*, because this will never actually happen in production; and a test that tests something that cannot happen in production has very limited value in telling you something useful.

Actually, you can mock static methods like `Locale.getISOCountries()` using [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito); but changing the behavior of a static method is highly inadvisable, because it doesn't just change the behavior for you - it changes it for anybody who calls it. So, there could be unintended consequences in the behavior, both nearby and in the rest of the code.

For example:

```
when(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(countryCode.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

Aside from changing the mutability semantics of the returned list (`Arrays.asList` allows `set`; `Collections.singletonList` doesn't), it is now inconsistent with other country-code-returning methods in the `Locale` class (e.g. `getISOCountryCodes(Type)`. Chasing down and fixing all such inconsistencies is nigh-on impossible.

What if we could use PowerMock to mock the return value of `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())`, i.e. a less generic use-case of the `Locale.getISOCountries()` method? This still suffers from the problems of unintended consequences - there could be other parts of the program which invoke `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())` where the mocked behavior isn't desirable.

What if we could use PowerMock to mock the return value of *just one specific call* to `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())`? That's brittle, for example, if another call is added, you'd have to make sure the test is correctly updated, otherwise the behavior would be inconsistent between the calls.

There isn't a good way to win the PowerMock battle.

---

There are an awful lot of words here, but the key point is that there are really rather difficult-to-deal-with consequences of trying to use mocking inappropriately: using the actual behavior (without mocks) is best; but, if a mock has to be used, it should not behave in a way that the real code never will.

Fortunately, Mockito is stopping you from doing this; but hopefully this answer has given a thorough explanation as to why it was the wrong approach in the first place.

---

## Dependency injection

With all of this said, there is a way to make your code work in the face of arbitrary country codes: [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Whilst there are lots of DI frameworks (e.g. Guice, Spring) which introduce a lot of power (and complexity and horror), dependency injection simply means: passing things as arguments.

If, for example, the code in which you want `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains(countryCode)` to be true occurs in a method, inject the country list as a parameter to that method:

```
class MyClass {
  void myMethod(List<String> countryCodes, String countryCode) {
    if (countryCodes.contains(countryCode)) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

or make it a constructor parameter:

```
class MyClass {
  private final List<String> countryCodes;

  MyClass(List<String> countryCodes) {
    // Defensive copy.
    this.countryCodes = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(countryCodes));
  }

  void myMethod(String countryCode) {
    if (countryCodes.contains(countryCode)) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

In your production code, pass in `Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())`; in test code, pass in whatever list you like.

But still: beware of the interaction between this code and code which uses `Locale.getISOCountries()` and allied methods directly in tests. If there is a risk of such an interaction, it remains safer to write your tests using the static `Local.getISOCountries()`.

Comment: I meant `when(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries()).contains("XYZ")).thenReturn(true);`

Comment: It throws exception as it returns false. So, how should I mock the necessary value? Or how should I check this line?

Comment: Amigo??? Any reply please?

Comment: I also tried with `when(Arrays.asList(Locale.getISOCountries())).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(countryCode.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));`